# How to make List::Util 'shuffle' reproduce same output in Perl

Tags: perl

Can Perl's shuffle be utilized such that each time it produces the outputs in the same order?

Comment: I think calling srand() each time with the same seed value before running shuffle would be enough.

Comment: Surelty the whole point of a shuffle is to produce a random order?

Comment: I was running some tests and I needed to get the same results to make sure that my code works fine. That's why I need it.

Comment: https://github.com/Scalar-List-Utils/Scalar-List-Utils/blob/master/ListUtil.xs#L916

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `srand()` function always with the same seed value (`123` in this case). E.g. I get:

```
$ perl -MList::Util=shuffle -E 'srand 123; say shuffle 1 .. 5'
41352
```

repeatable every time. Without the [srand()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/srand.html) call it differs.